# How to compile single file assembly?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I've got a web application project with a few asmx files with code behind. How can I compile them so there is a separate dll for each file, i.e. rather than project.dll I get file1.dll, file2.dll etc.? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do that, but I recommend creating a project for each service, and I would also recommend using the same public key for all projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A single .NET project compiles to a single .NET assembly. If you want multiple assemblies, make multiple projects.